# Xcode custom font not showing in app

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I have downloaded Open Sans font and added all the `.tff` files into my Xcode project, and have checked the checkbox in "Target Membership" pane for each file. I have added the `UIAppFonts` key and values in Info.plist, and I am sure that the values are typo-free. Plus, the `.tff` files are added to "Copy Bundle Resources", and the custom font is showing up in Interface Builder. And then I changed the font of all the labels to Open Sans in the Interface Builder (no code).

But when I run the app in the simulator, all the labels and buttons are showing the system font in ultra small sizes, like this:

[image]

One thing to note is that I am using Xcode 7 beta 5, and the app's Base SDK is iOS 9.

But why is there this problem? Is it a bug? Thanks!

Comment: Did you set the font of the labels and buttons? - You'll have to do that you know...

Comment: @Cabus Oh yes I did.

Comment: could you give a piece of code of how you did that? - it can be tricky because you have to use the 'PostScript' name of the font

Comment: @Cabus I specified the font in Interface Builder. I did not use any code.

Comment: Try to restart the xcode

Comment: See my discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/q/31369253/2353523 Apple has done some major overhaul concerning fonts but I haven't see anything in the release notes. Almost all of my apps use custom fonts but for some reason they they didn't transition well with the Xcode upgrade. I noticed this the first beta 7. What I ultimately ended up having to do was set the font programmatically. It resolved the issue, albeit, not user friendly

Comment: @soulshined I will try.

Comment: @soulshined I created a test project in Xcode 7 beta 5 and the custom font showed!

Comment: yes, @Blip that's strange, i would try setting it programmatically, that's the only thing that helped me in select cases

Comment: @soulshined I found the problem. When I set a bigger font for a different size class, the labels come out super small. This is a bug, a size class bug!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check That fonts inside the proyect are part of the target.
Select fonts, verify the property **Target Membership** for your app is *checked* at the right in File Inspector.

That solved the problem for me: [image: Target Membership is in te property inspector at the right]

Comment: This worked for me! thanks!, Should be the accepted answer!

Comment: So easy answer, but so helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Blip, here's a photo of what I did in an empty "Single View" project.  And, I could see the font on sim and IB editor.  Anything look different for your project?  Maybe recreate the basics in a new project, just to double check?  All of my notes on the image were associated with my original thoughts...just use them for reference as you double check things.

[image]

Comment: I am using Xcode 7 beta 5, and I see that you are using Xcode 6 in the screenshot. Perhaps it is the problem with the IDE?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered this problem too. But it only happened for one font-style of a font-family, the others worked fine.
I could only solve it by using this font in a button, then the font was also available for other controls such as labels or the large title.