# where is STHeitiSC in XIB?Is it deprecated?

Tags: ios, uifont

I try to custom fonts like I used to do in XIB,after upgrade Xcode to 7 ,

I cannot find `STHeitiSC`  in the font list?

Is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it is no longer a supported IB font. See my issues with it here : [Xcode 7 iOS9 font no longer recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369253/xcode-7-ios9-font-no-longer-recognized)

This font is usually reserved and intended only for Chinese text. However, you can still import the font to your project, add it to your plist and perform accordingly as any other custom font would.